# How to build berkeley db on linux

Tags: berkeley-db

I've downloaded [Berkeley DB source codes](http://download.oracle.com/otn/berkeley-db/db-18.1.25.zip) from Oracle's website. After unpacking the zip file, there does not have any files in `build_unix` directory. There exists an directory which contains sln file for build it on windows using visual studio.

My question is if there is a sample Makefile & Configure script for building this db on unix-like systems such as Linux.

Comment: This is covered in their docs distributed with the source under ./docs/installation/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The makefile and configure scripts are located at DB_ROOT/dist/* , DB_ROOT is the root directory of the unzipped source codes.
The build guide is available at https://docs.oracle.com/database/bdb181/html/installation/build_unix.html#build_unix_intro